# Is there a way to remove rounded corners in iTunes? And to make icon transparent?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icons, itunes

I have marked my app icon as prerendered and when installed, the icon looks like it should look like, but the iTunes Icon still looks odd. First, background is black instead of transparent. Second, round corner are added, which looks bad.

Do you have a advice?
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/das-gro-e-film-quiz-deutsch/id604179483?l=de&ls=1&mt=8

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any web-tool to see how my image would look like in the App Store? I don't know if it works, but this is the original image:
http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQClV_DIC94ZrORR&url=http%3A%2F%2Fa4.mzstatic.com%2Fus%2Fr30%2FPurple%2Fv4%2Fcc%2F53%2Ff5%2Fcc53f5f5-275d-c954-e3db-9bd59d6a6814%2Fmzl.snciqlps.png
I really did not expect the look in store...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. there is no way to do that for apps submitted to the AppStore. Marking the icon as pre rendered will only remove the gloss effect that added by default.

(Users of jailbroken devices can customize the UI)

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't make it transparent or have anything but rounded corners, it is basically a trademark of apple. The only way someone could have it transparent or not have rounded corners is if the users device is jailbroken.

Answer (score 2):

App Store icons don't have transparency, and always have the round corners. Pre-rendered only means iTunes is not putting the glow effect on top of it.

Just give your icon a colored background (maybe with a gradient) to make it look nicer.